# Cannot remotely debug java project by using DDMS or Monitor in Sdk on android >=5 (API Level >= 21)

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, remote-debugging, ddms

There is a java project which was compiled to `sample.jar` as debug version, converted to `sample.dex` by using `dx`, pushed to `Android emulator(Android 5.1.1)`, and run on the device. This project was developed to boot specific `App` on Android device and test the `App`.

The sample.dex is indeed successfully run on devices because all the behaviores and outputs are correct. The problem deeply confused us is that we cannot debug it step by step as an `Remote java application` by using `DDMS`/`Android device monitor`, which is useful in `Android 4.4.2(API Level 19)`.

PS: the emulator is rooted and I have tried several ways to fixed this problem, including selectting the `USB debug` in `Developer mode` and change the API Level to 23, all these efforts do not work.

How to fix it.....

Comment: in addition, I have used `Debug.waitForDebugger()` in source code which works correctly on Android 4.4.2(API Level 19) and shows `sending WAIT chunk` information. However, it doesn't work on Android 5.1.1(API Level 21) or API Level 23 or show any message about `WAIT`. 
Fanally, the `android.jar` we used to develop the project `sample` is from `API Level 20`, `Sdk/platform/android-20`